# Sacar foto o coger de la libreria swift 3

Tags: swift2, swift3

¿Cómo puedo poner un botón que al hacer click, de la opción de elegir una foto de la librería o de sacar una directamente?

De momento sólo puedo poner mediante código una de las dos opciones.

```
@IBAction func cogerImagen(_ sender: UIButton) {
 self.imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.imagePicker.isEditing = true
        present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        self.imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        /*let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) cómo ya haces. Código de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25514262/1468942) en el SO Original:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func btnClicked(){

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
            println("Button capture")


            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

    })

    imageView.image = image

}
}
```

Creo que dado tu código concreto es simplemente modificar el `imagePicker` que tienes definido para que sea de tipo `SavedPhotosAlbum` en lugar de `photoLibrary`:

```
self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
```

Asimismo el `UIButton` definido es el que te permite escoger.